# Javafx FXML cannot load controller from other package

Tags: java, javafx, package

I have trouble gettings a ressource to access a controller located in another package.

The FXML is loaded from another FXML file, which i am able to access the controller for.

I have the following files:

- Main
- TabSelector which is loaded from Main
- Controller for TabSelector
- Component which is loaded from the TabSelector.FXML
- The controller for component

[The files is stored in this structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd9Gy.png)

The component files:
Component:fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<Label fx:id="label" text="Hello World" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ComponentPackage.Component" />
```

Component.java:

```
package ComponentPackage;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Component implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

}
```

The TabSelector works.
The Component works, if i remove fx:controller from the FXML file.  Because of this i know the problem is loading the controller.
If i move TabSelector.java to ComponentPackage, i have the same problem. Because of this i know that the problem is accessing the controller in another package.
How should i go around accessing Component.java from ComponentPackage?
I get this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/MathiasLerkenfeltBru/Desktop/example/out/production/NetworkTool/Resources/TabSelector.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at NetworkTool/Program.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,18]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2538)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application Program.Main
```

TabSelector.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Program.TabSelector"><Tab fx:id="ComponentTab" closable="false" text="Component">
    <fx:include fx:id="nicTool" source="Component.fxml" />
</Tab>
</TabPane>
```

Comment: The issue is in `TabSelector.fxml`: is that the FXML file you posted? Make sure there is no blank line or other whitespace before the `<?xml ...?>` processing instruction.

Comment: No the one i posted is Component.fxml. I will ad TagSelector.fxml

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong there. Double check there is no white space (including blank lines) and no other content before your `<?xml ... ?>` processing instruction, and if not I’d try cleaning and rebuilding the project.